# How do I access the value of a field returned by a Restful API

Tags: rest, api, powershell, restful-authentication

I have a very basic requirement to call a RESTful API. I am currently on a Windows 2012 R2 server using version 4 of PowerShell.

Here is my code:

```
$logon = @{
    username = 'blah'
    password='blah'
}

$body = $logon | ConvertTo-Json 

$URI = 'https://URL/Logon'

Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose
```

I get the following result:

```
{"LogonResult":"blahblahblah"}
```

How do I extract just the logon token to reuse as a variable? I've already put a variable at the beginning of the command:

```
   $token =  (Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose).content
```

This returns the entire result, not just the token.  How do I get just the token as a result?

Comment: Hey, no the endpoint doesn't have a public API.  I have tried both GET and POST, for that particular command (Logon) it requires a POST according to the documentation.  It should also return a logon token, which i then use to issue further commands once I've logged in.

Comment: just to add some more information.  When i purposely put in a wrong password I get the following:  https://URL/
Logon with -1-byte payload
Invoke-WebRequest : {"ErrorCode":"ITATS004E","ErrorMessage":"Authentication failure for User 8780575."}
At D:\test-websdk.ps1:10 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/j ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ same as original error

Comment: added server logs to main post - easier to read

Comment: There's been progress, I get a returned value now updated in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the returned `LogonResult` property as follows:

```
$token =  ((Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose).content | ConvertFrom-JSON).LogonResult
```

Or you simplify this by using `Invoke-RestMethod` as this returns just the content and converts it to a PSObject automatically:

```
$token =  (Invoke-RestMethod -URI $URI -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose).LogonResult
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've edited your question so that it now relates just to this answer (as the other information was now unnecessary / confusing to future readers).